# Java - Discrepancy between Online Calculator and My CRC-16/EN-13757 Code Output

Tags: java, crc

Im currently working on implementing a CRC-16/EN-13757 algorithm in my code (im reusing a code i wrote sometime before), and Im encountering an issue where the output from my code differs from the result from an online calculater.
https://crccalc.com/?crc=403126215E78563412000022&method=CRC-16/EN-13757&datatype=hex&outtype=0

The polynomial is x^16 + x^13 + x^12 + x^11 + x^10 + x^8 + x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + 1, initial value is 0.

```
public class crcTest {
    private static final int INITIAL_VALUE = 0x0000;
    private static final int POLYNOMIAL = 0x3D65;
    private static final int XOR_OUT = 0xFFFF;

    public static byte[] calc(byte[] data) {
        int crc = INITIAL_VALUE;

        for (byte b : data) {
            crc = crc^(b & 0xFF);
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                if ((crc & 0x0001) != 0) {
                    crc = (crc >>> 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL;
                } else {
                    crc >>>= 1;
                }
            }
        }

        crc = crc^XOR_OUT;
        return new byte[]{(byte) ((crc >> 8) & 0xff), (byte) (crc & 0xff)};
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] data = {0x40, 0x31, 0x26, 0x21, 0x5e, 0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x22};
        byte[] crcBytes = calc(data);

        for (byte b : crcBytes) {
            System.out.printf("%02X ", b);
        }
    }
}
```

The results Im getting are 0xC920, but im expecting 0x5E87.
I tried looking for sample code for CRC-16/EN-13757 but it didnt help a lot.
I would greatly appreciate any suggestion to help find the error.

```
public class CRC { 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int crc = 0x0000;          // initial value
        int polynomial = 0x3D65;   

        byte[] data = {0x40, 0x31, 0x26, 0x21, 0x5e, 0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x22};

        for (byte b : data) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                boolean bit = ((b   >> (7-i) & 1) == 1);
                boolean c15 = ((crc >> 15    & 1) == 1);
                crc <<= 1;
                if (c15 ^ bit) crc ^= polynomial;
             }
        }

        crc &= 0xffff;
        System.out.println("CRC16-CCITT = " + Integer.toHexString(crc));
    }

}
```

Tried this code from another post but im still getting different values.

Comment: Make sure there's not a stray trailing newline in one of the calculator inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, checked it, and still got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to shift up.

```
        for (byte b : data) {
            crc = crc ^ ((b & 0xFF) << 8);
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                if ((crc & 0x8000) != 0) {
                    crc = (crc << 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL;
                } else {
                    crc <<= 1;
                }
            }
        }
```